# iPod Classic 5.5 160Gb Euro Volume Cap

Tags: ipod, sound-volume

I've just bought an iPod Classic 5.5, and the volume is too low.
I have searched through google and, though i find a lot of people with the same problem, i can't seem to find a solution.

and no, it's not the 'volume limit' option in the settings.

Does anybody know how to hack this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not loud enough for what application? I'd start by trying the iPod using different headphones because volume levels can vary greatly and, using earbuds with better isolation allow for lower listening levels. 20 years down the road your ears will thank you (by not ringing in an annoying way.)

If you can't find an acceptable pair of *buds* consider a portable headphone amplifier like the [**FiiO E5**](http://www.fiio.com.cn/product/index.aspx?ID=6). It's available for $20 or so, and won't void your warranty.

---

I just realized that you specified a Euro iPod so I will also [link to software](http://www.randgruppe.info/ipod/) that claims to remove the *euro volume cap*. I can't verify or guarantee it's function, I don't have ready access to Windows computer or a Euro-market iPod for testing. Do your own research and apply this patch at your own risk.

Comment: thanks. the application is headphone listening. I have a great pair of headphones, I have a 30GB iPod Video and the sound levels are far greater. I will try that software when i get to a windows computer. thanks

Comment: *Great* and *efficient* don't necessarily go hand-in-hand, which is why headphone snobs…I mean…affeciandos use headphone amps to drive their high-end *cans*. That being said, you're hearing a reduction in SPL (sound pressure level, aka *volume*) relative to your old iPod so by all means try the patch if you're comfortable doing so. Let us know how it works out by posting your own answer here–or by editing mine.